# Preventing UIButtons in a UITableViewCell from being selected with the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UIButton` in its content view. When I tap on the cell to select it, the button’s background image also switches to its highlighted state. I’ve tried preventing it by implementing `-setSelected:animated:` in the cell like so:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    [[self exampleButton] setSelected:NO];
}
```

No such luck; the button still changes its style. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `exampleButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO`.

Comment: Should have specified that I tried that. The problem is that I *want* the button to change its image when you tap on the button. So, I tried setting this to `NO` before calling `[super setSelected:selected animated:animated]`, but no such luck.

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear, you want the button to change its image, but not revert to the highlighted state. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope. I want the button to change its image with the *button* is tapped, but *not* when the cell is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change highlighted state not selected.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    _exampleButton.highlighted = NO;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:highlighted animated:animated];
    _exampleButton.highlighted = NO;
}
```